# syntax error insert into statement vba 2022

Tags: database, vb.net, syntax-error

I've tried a lot of things, but I always get the mistake.

This script i use

```
Module Module1
    Public usertype As String
    Public userId As String
    Public result As String
    Public sql As String
    Public cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Public dt As New DataTable
    Public da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Public Function myDBmodule() As OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Return New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" &
                                         Application.StartupPath & "\db_billing.accdb;Persist Security Info=True")
    End Function
    Public con As OleDb.OleDbConnection = myDBmodule()
    Public strcon As OleDbConnection = myDBmodule()
    Public Sub myselectstatements(ByVal sql As String, ByVal dtg As DataGridView)

        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            dtg.DataSource = dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        con.Close()
        ' Form1.TextBox1.Text = Total().ToString("c")
    End Sub
    Public Sub mysql(ByVal sql As String)
        Try
            con.Open()
            da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
            dt = New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return
        End Try
        con.Close()
    End Sub


       Try

            If Label82.Text = "Desktop Detail" Then
                sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (PHASE,FA_TAGGING,IT_TAGGING,DESKTOP_MODEL,SN,WARRANTY_START,WARRANTY_EXPIRED,RAM,STORAGE," _
                                                    & "MONITOR_MODEL,MONITOR_SN,UPS_MODEL,UPS_SN,UPS_WARRANTY_STARTS,UPS_WARRANTY_EXPIRED,LOCATION," _
                                                     & "DEPARTMENT,COST_CENTRE,USERNAME,EMPNO,POSITION) _
                                                    VALUES('" & ComboBox6.Text & "','" & TxtFA.Text & "','" & fatxt.Text & "','" &
                                                    TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text _
                                                    & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox7.Text _
                                                    & "','" & TextBox6.Text & "','" & ComboBox1.Text _
                                                    & "','" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & ComboBox2.Text _
                                                    & "','" & TextBox8.Text & "','" & TextBox11.Text _
                                                    & "','" & TextBox9.Text & "','" & ComboBox3.Text _
                                                    & "','" & ComboBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox10.Text _
                                                    & "','" & TextBox12.Text & "','" & IDNUMBER.Text _
                                                    & "','" & ComboBox5.Text & "')"
                mysql(sql)
                MsgBox("Customer Save", , "Save")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: This is crazy vulnerable to SQL injection issues. But I have good news! Fixing the SQL injection will probably _also_ fix the error in the question, since it likely comes from a stray apostrophe in the data.

Answer (score 4):

The first problem is you have 22 items in the insert list, but only substitute 21 values.

The second problem is the `mysql()` method is fundamentally flawed in at least three different ways. You want it to look more like this:

```
Public Function RunSQL(SQL As String, Parameters As IEnumerable(Of OleDbParameter)) As DataTable
    ' Actually return the data, instead of using a global variable
    Dim result As New DataTable()

    ' Thanks to **connection pooling**, it really is better to 
    '  create new connection and command objects for every query.
    Using con As New OleDbConnection("connection string here"), _
          cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQL, con)

        ' This fixes the nasty SQL injection issue, which was a HUGE problem before
        If Parameters IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each p As OleDbParameter In Parameters
               cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
            Next
        End If

        con.Open()
        Using rdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
           result.Load(rdr)
           rdr.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
    Return result
End Function
```

Then you'd call it like this (Note: I can't demonstrate it perfectly, since we're missing on the values to include):

```
' String literals can cross multiple lines now
Dim sql As String = "
INSERT INTO table1 
 (PHASE, FA_TAGGING, IT_TAGGING, DESKTOP_MODEL, SN, WARRANTY_START, WARRANTY_EXPIRED, RAM, 
  STORAGE, MONITOR_MODEL, MONITOR_SN, UPS_MODEL, UPS_SN, UPS_WARRANTY_STARTS,
  UPS_WARRANTY_EXPIRED, LOCATION, DEPARTMENT, COST_CENTRE, USERNAME, EMPNO, POSITION)
VALUES 
(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
  
' Parameter values are mapped to the ? placeholders based on the orders they appear
' in the SQL string/parameters collection.
' So the names don't matter here... it just helpful to ensure we match them up right.
' This is *even better* if we also set type information (on some platforms, there can be a huge performance penalty if we don't).
Dim Parameters As New List(Of OleDbParameter) From {
    New OleDbParameter("Phase", ComboBox6.Text),
    New OleDbParameter("FA_Tagging", TxtFA.Text),
    New OleDbParameter("IT_Tagging", fatxt.Text),
    New OleDbParameter("DESKTOP_MODEL", TextBox3.Text),
    New OleDbParameter("SN", TextBox2.Text),
    New OleDbParameter("WARRANTY_START", DateTime.Parse(TextBox4.Text)),
    New OleDbParameter("WARRANTY_EXPIRED", DateTime.Parse(TextBox5.Text)),
    New OleDbParameter("RAM", TextBox7.Text),
    New OleDbParameter("DEPARTMENT", TextBox6.Text),
    New OleDbParameter("STORAGE", ... ), ' I suspect the missing value is near here or just above
    New OleDbParameter("MONITOR_MODEL", ComboBox1.Text ), 
    New OleDbParameter("MONITOR_SN", TextBox1.Text ), 
    New OleDbParameter("UPS_MODEL", ComboBox2.Text),
    New OleDbParameter("UPS_SN", TextBox8.Text),
    New OleDbParameter("UPS_WARRANTY_STARTS", DateTime.Parse(TextBox11.Text)),
    New OleDbParameter("UPS_WARRANTY_EXPIRED",DateTime.Parse(TextBox9.Text)),
    New OleDbParameter("LOCATION", ComboBox3.Text),
    New OleDbParameter("DEPARTMENT", ComboBox4.Text),
    New OleDbParameter("COST_CENTRE", TextBox10.Text),
    New OleDbParameter("USERNAME", TextBox12.Text),
    New OleDbParameter("EMPNO",Integer.Parse(IDNUMER.Text)),
    New OleDbParameter("POSITION",ComboBox5.Text)
}

dt = RunSQL(SQL, Parameters)
```

Comment: (Upvoted for your generosity of writing all those parameters :) )